# Unix/Linux find command to use multiple conditions?

Tags: linux, unix, find

I have a requirement, where i have to look for a file named "sales.trigger" in the directory "/dev/trigger_dir/". I should look for the file only if it is
Condition 1- the file was modified in the last 3 days
OR
Condition 2- the file was created on a Sunday or a Monday.

How can do I do it using find command? I tried doing something like this

find . -type f ( -mtime -3 -name "salestrigger" -or -type f ( -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | egrep "^(Sun|Mon)" | cut -f 2- )  )

I am missing some syntax. Could somebody help?

Comment: Are you looking for `/dev/trigger_dir/sales.trigger` (fixed name and path, only check conditions), the file `salestrigger` (without dot) in any subdirectory of the current dir, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try combining find with awk and so:

```
find . -name "*.salestrigger" -type f -printf '%Ts\t%Ta\t%p\n' | awk -F '\t' '$1 > (strftime("%s")-259200) || $2 == "Sun" || $2 == "Mon" { print $3 }'
```

Find all files named salestrigger and print the file modification in epoch format, followed by a tab, the shorthand day of modification, a tab and then the file path. Process this in awk, using the epoch date to check whether the file was modified in the last 3 days (the epoch date now minus 259200 seconds), the day is "Sun" or the day is "Mon". Print the file path (the third tab delimited field).

Comment: No worries. If it meets your needs, please take the time to up vote and access the solution